# Binding data with WPF/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a problem with data binding (binding update?). After launching the application, I load the images and want to display their histograms on a scale of 0-255. The variable 'frequency' already has the data ready. And I want to bind them to xaml to show some kind of chart. XAML code works well with some static data, but assigning value to 'frequency' it doesn't show anything.

XAML:

```
        <ItemsControl Name="ItemsControlName" ItemsSource="{Binding ChartValues}">
            <ItemsControl.DataContext>
                <local:DicomChart/>
            </ItemsControl.DataContext>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Height="{Binding }" Width="4" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                   Fill="#eee" Stroke="Gray" Margin="-1.0"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

C#:

```
    private void RegionGrowing(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int[] frequency = new int[256];

        for (int m = 0; m < 512; m++)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < 512; n++)
            {
                frequency[database[pictureIndex, m, n]] += 1;
            }
        }

        DicomChart dc = new DicomChart();
        dc.ChartValues = frequency.ToArray();
    }
```

DicomClass class:

```
public class DicomChart
{

    public DicomChart()
    {


    }

    public int[] ChartValues { get; set; }
    
}
```

Comment: You have to use ObservableCollection<int> which raises event `CollectionChanged` in order to have an updated UI in WPF. When your UI is rendered and the array is bound to the ItemsControl it doesn't know that it's changed. This is where ObservableCollection<T> is needed.

Comment: Your binding should be like this ItemsSource="{Binding ChartValues, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

Comment: @DmitriyPolyanskiy Do you mean changing "public int[] ChartValues {get; set;}" to "public ObservableCollection<int> ChartValues {get; set;}" ?

Comment: @tm607 Yes! That's correct!

Comment: @DmitriyPolyanskiy I tried this, but it ain't working :( I also tried working with PropertyChangedEventHandler but it also failed

Comment: @tm607, something wrong here with the way you bind. Can you post the full code of your view? According to the event style method name you use it in view code behind, right?

Comment: @DmitriyPolyanskiy this is my xaml: https://pastebin.com/k3L9m0jD - perhaps I should have added that the Region Growing method is called by the checkbox. If checkbox clicked than show me histogram of current image (defined by this pictureIndex variable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use additional class like DicomChartItem and fill observable collection with it, something like that

C#:

```
public class DicomChart   
{
    public ObservableCollection<DicomChartItem> ChartItems{ get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<DicomChartItem>();
}
public class DicomChartItem
{
 public int _Value { get; set; }

    public DicomChartItem(int Value)
    {
        _Value = Value;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```XAML
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ChartItems}">
        <ItemsControl.DataContext>
            <local:DicomChart/>
        </ItemsControl.DataContext>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DicomChartItem}">
                <Rectangle Height="{Binding _Value}" Width="4" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                   Fill="#eee" Stroke="Gray" Margin="-1.0"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Observable collection must be filled in the loop for calling CollectionChanged event, in another case you need to use PropertyChanged event from INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

C#:

```
private void RegionGrowing(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int[] frequency = new int[256];

        for (int m = 0; m < 512; m++)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < 512; n++)
            {
                frequency[database[pictureIndex, m, n]] += 1;
            }
        }

        DicomChart dc = new DicomChart();

        foreach (var item in frequency)
            dc.ChartItems.Add(new DicomChartItem(item));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately the code does not work for me. I followed your idea and I worked with it a little, but it still doesn't show this chart

Comment: Try set DicomChart instance which was created in RegionGrowing method as DataContext of UserControl. I think your usercontrol binded to another DicomChart instance, without items. Probaly it is.

Comment: I think I set everything up well. In "properties" (right-bottom window), when I expand DataContext I see (Dicom Chart) and ChartItems (Collection) under it.

Comment: I mean in RegionGrowing you create new DiconChart object but your UserControl binded to another which was created on app start automatically (because you set it in XAML tags as DataContext). If RegionGrowing method located in your Window/Control class, try do something like: ItemsControlName.DataContext = dc, after creating and filing it with data.

Comment: It works, thanks for your help, I am so grateful :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to replace int[] with `ObservableCollection<int>` like I said. It's not going to work with a simple array because UI isn't notified about changes.
2. Add x:Name="Items" to your ItemsControl in order to be able to access it from the code behind;
3. Add this code in your RegionGrowing: var ds = (DicomChart) Items.DataContext;
4. Add values to your ds object like ds.ChartValues.Add(<your_value>).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, your solution also works